# How to Publish a Multimedia Component in SDL Tridion 2013?

Tags: 2013, binary

I want to Publish an image in a Multimedia Component in SDL Tridion 2013. It should preserve the folder structure as it it was created.

If I have created the Multimedia Component in a Folder say `Images/abc/xyz/my image`, after publishing it should be `Images/abc/xyz/my image` on the web server also.

Comment: You might want to show what you've done and where you're stuck exactly, along with any research you've already done.

Answer (score 13):

A while back I've written a TBB that does exactly what you want, including checking if a Structure Group exists that mirrors the path of the Folder (based on relative WebDav paths).

Here is the link: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/publish-an-image-to-a-structure-group-mirroring-folder

Answer (score 6):

In order to achieve this I suggest reading the API manual, and look for the `AddBinary()` method. This will allow you to publish the file with a specific filename, and bind it to a Structure Group. You will need to make Structure Groups to match your Folder structure in order to fully achieve what you want.

Answer (score 4):

As Chris mentioned, the `addBinary` method (from the namespace: `Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Rendering.RenderedItem`) is what you need, here's the options available:

- AddBinary(Component); AddBinary(Component, String);
- AddBinary(Component, StructureGroup);
- AddBinary(Component,StructureGroup, String);
- AddBinary(Stream, String, String, Component,String);
- AddBinary(Stream, String, StructureGroup, String, Component,String);

If you wish to publish to a specific location, you can supply a StructureGroup parameter to addBinary, the image will then be published into the directory related to the particular StructureGroup.